# Java Multicast Socket not working on Windows (SocketPermission Exception)

Tags: java, windows, networking, socketexception, multicastsocket

When starting a Multicast java socket on windows I get the following error (firewall deactivated):

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 230.0.0.1 connect,accept,resolve)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkMulticast(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(Unknown Source)
        at ch.uzh.ifi.group10.client.ServiceBrowser.(ServiceBrowser.java:49)
        at ch.uzh.ifi.group10.server.RMIServer.startServer(RMIServer.java:176)
        at ch.uzh.ifi.group10.server.RMIServer.main(RMIServer.java:279)

It seems like I am unable to join the multicast group because the programm has no permissions for the socket. The funny thing is that the same code works without any issues on linux (ubuntu 11.10). Also I have tried adding a socket permission to the security.policy file (Permission java.net.SocketPermission "230.0.0.1", "connect, accept, listen, resolve";) This has not helped either.

I'm stuck as I can't find any other place where the issue could be or what I'm missing...any ideas?

Comment: are you building a standalone app or an applet ?

Comment: a standalone app. I did see that applets need to be signed on windows, but this should not apply to a standalone app or am I wrong?

Comment: I should correct: I found the same error running on linux (before I was running the server form eclipse on linux). This is confusing me even more...

Comment: I found the problem. The security manager was not being properly loaded. For some reason Eclipse does not need a security manager to successfully run the code, so this issue was only found when the code was being executed outside of the eclipse environment.

Comment: Java doesn't need a security manager either. Are you sure you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The security manager was not being properly loaded. For some reason Eclipse does not need a security manager to successfully run